# Determine the window under the cursor

Tags: cocoa, macos

Press Cmd + Shift + 4 + Space and start roaming around the screen. It determines which window I'm over and highlights it. I suppose it asks every window about its size and position. How to do the same thing from my own Cocoa app? Determine the window under the cursor and ask about its different parameters? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the Quartz Window Services (`CGWindow`) API, specifically the function [`CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/CGWindow_Reference/Reference/Functions.html).

Comment: Thank you! And looks like this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286274/front-most-window-using-cgwindowlistcopywindowinfo is elaborating on that.

Comment: Doesn't the above returns information about 'the frontmost window' and not 'the window the mouse is over'? Edit: Nevermind, I forgot that you can iterate over all bounding rectangles to find which window the mouse is over.