# Cocoa CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo & AXUIElementSetAttributeValue

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm using the following piece of code to get all windows:

```
CFArrayRef windows = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly | kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements, kCGNullWindowID);
```

This gives me an array of dictionaries as found here: [Front most window using CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286274/front-most-window-using-cgwindowlistcopywindowinfo)

Then I check their bounds to see if the mouse is in it, and the first I find is is the one my mouse is over.

Then I would like to be able to move it. I know how to use `AXUIElementSetAttributeValue` to move a window, though then I need a `AXUIElementRef`, which I can't figure out how to get out of the dictionary.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to go from a window number to an `AXUIElementRef`.

The closest you can get is to find the owner of the window, then ask it through Accessibility for its windows and look for one with the same title—but an app may have more than one window with the same title, so you need to figure out what you'll do in that case.

The only ways to move another application's windows are by *AppleScript* or by *Accessibility*. Using *Accessibility* is much more reliable than *AppleScript* (many, if not most, apps have incomplete and/or flaky scripting support). You can get the process ID and window title from the same window dictionary that gives the window number, but that's as specific as you can get. With AppleScript, you could only use the window's index within its application's window list, and hope that the list hasn't changed order in the split-second between you computing the index and trying to use it.

Comment: *Curse word here*, that sucks. Guess I'll have to find an other way. Is there perhaps a way to get from a window number to something else I can use to move that window?

Comment: @TheOddler: Nope. The only ways to move another application's windows are by AppleScript and by Accessibility, and Accessibility is much more reliable than AppleScript (many, if not most, apps have incomplete and/or flaky scripting support). You can get the process ID and window title from the same window dictionary that gives the window number, but that's as specific as you can get. (With AppleScript, you could use the window's index within its application's window list, and hope that the list hasn't changed order in the split-second between you computing the index and trying to use it.)

Comment: Ok thanks, then I'll have to try something else. Thanks a lot!