# Cocoa: How to track and record the user activity?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I started to develop my first OS X application as an exercise to learn Objective-C and Cocoa. It's a menu bar application that continuously records (writes in a text file) the names of the applications used (those displayed when making a cmd + tab, not all processes shown by the Activity Monitor) and the time spent using them. Something like:

```
Name: TextEdit
Start: 10.37am
End: 11.02am

Name: Adobe Photoshop
Start: 11.02am
End: 11.12am

Name: TextEdit
Start: 11.12am
End: 11.13am

Name: Mail
Start: 11.13am
End: 11.28am
…
```

So far, I've managed to create a basic menulet application but I'm already stuck as I really don't know how to get these data. Does anyone has an idea of where to start? Thank you very much in advance!

David

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo to get a list of all the current windows. Filter out the non-user windows and then find the topmost one. Whatever app it's from is the frontmost app.

This answer will help you find the frontmost window:

[Front most window using CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286274/front-most-window-using-cgwindowlistcopywindowinfo)