# How does one 'attach' a button to a window of another process?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

I am making a plugin for a [Mac application](https://www.telestream.net/screenflow/overview.htm). I want the plugin to be easy to use so I would like to *'attach'* UI Elements to the application's window. Sadly the application doesn't have an API which would allow this functionality natively, so I have to develop a technique on my own.

Traditionally on Windows OS I would use [`SetParent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633541(v=vs.85).aspx) with a borderless window containing the controls. However on Mac I understand that such a function doesn't exist.

However this leaves me in a bit of a dilemma. Does anyone know of an alternative I can use which would accomplish this goal?

Comment: What does the plug-in do? Generally you would use the accessibility api to interact with other applications.

Comment: It uses UI automation for the most part to automate certain functions of the application. Also adds certain features such  as reversing video clips etc. I guess I have to use UI Automation for this as well then... Shame there isn't anything else which is cleaner...

Comment: [This might help](http://idevapps.com/forum/showthread.php?tid=1791) and also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286274/front-most-window-using-cgwindowlistcopywindowinfo)

Comment: If it is a plug-in, and as such loaded into the target application, you can simple access the window with [[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function to the plugin that requires the target window to be inserted and the plugin can then be used to add objects to the inputed window eg.

```
- (void)addObjectToWindow:(NSWindow *)theWindow {
    if (!theWindow) {return;} // Exits if the window is nil
    NSButton *addButton = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10, 10, 30, 100)]; // modify the NSMakeRect numbers to change the size and position of the button
    [addButton setTitle:@"Button Title"]; // Sets the button text
    [[theWindow contentView] addSubview:addButton]; // Adds the button to the Windows view
}
```

Thats all :D, this will only work if the application sends this function to the plugin.

Hope this helped :)

Comment: I guess there is no way to tell the application to send this function to the plugin right?

Comment: Well if the application is not a custom one then how will it know to load the plugin in the first place?

Comment: The plugin uses mostly UI Automation. So it is never 'loaded in' per se